# How can I trace where potential exceptions might be thrown from?

Tags: .net, exception, reflection, reflector, redgate

We have many questions here about stack traces and analyzing exceptions that have been thrown.

I am using RedGate Reflector to examine the workings of some .net classes.  In particular, I am looking at the `ConnectionString` property of the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` object.  Reflector indicates that this property may throw an `ArgumentException` if an invalid connection string is supplied.

My question is: given that this property may throw this particular exception, how can I analyze the code to find where the exception might be thrown from?  The property calls another function to set the value.  This function does not throw the `ArgumentException` directly.  I want to know how I can find where this exception might be thrown from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used it but you might look at Jason Bock's [ExceptionFinder for Reflector](http://exfinderreflector.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I have never used it before, but I think another Red Gate product, [Exception Hunter](http://www.red-gate.com/products/exception_hunter/index.htm), is designed to do this.

Comment: Does anyone here use this tool?